# Adding custom tag helpers

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I've been trying to add a custom tag helper, but when I try to add the assembly as a reference in the _ViewImports.cshtml it doesn't recognise it.

I'm doing this (_ViewImports.cshtml):

```
@using ProjectName.Web.Main
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@addTagHelper *, TagHelpers
```

and also I've tried:

```
@addTagHelper *, ProjectName.Web.Main.TagHelpers
```

my tag helper is the following:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers;
namespace ProjectName.Web.Main.TagHelpers
{
    [HtmlTargetElement(Attributes="class")]
    public class CssClassTagHelper : TagHelper
    {
        public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
        {
            output.Attributes.Add(new TagHelperAttribute("class","testing"));

        }
    }
}
```

but when I run the app, I get the following exception:

> Cannot resolve TagHelper containing assembly 'TagHelpers'. Error:
>   Could not load file or assembly 'TagHelpers, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot
>   find the file specified. @addTagHelper *, TagHelpers

I already have googled it but I'm getting mixed answers between the different dotnetcore releases, so far I haven't found any solution.

I'm using RC2.

any ideas, suggestions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to Asp.Net Core docs:

> To expose all of the Tag Helpers in this project (which creates an
>   assembly named AuthoringTagHelpers), you would use the following:

```
@using AuthoringTagHelpers 
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@addTagHelper "*, AuthoringTagHelpers"
```

In other words, second parameter of `addTagHelper` is an assembly name not a namespace.

So you should use `ProjectName.Web.Main` (I assumed that your project name is) in `_ViewImports.cshtml` :

```
@using ProjectName.Web.Main
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@addTagHelper *, ProjectName.Web.Main
```

Comment: thanks dude! this solved it for me. such a small thing causing such an issue :-D SHot Man!